# Disconnect from bluetooth speakers on sleep, reconnect on wake

Tags: macos, bluetooth, speakers

I have bluetooth harman kardon soundsticks. They're great but they stay connected to my macbook air during sleep. This means I can't pair my iPhone with them when my MacBook's sleeping. Is there any neat way of scripting (or otherwise) the macbook to disconnect/reconnect on sleep/wake.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I found for this problem was deactivating the "allow bluetooth devices to wake the computer" option in "System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced...".

Not really a neat solution if you want to use your keyboard or mouse to wake the computer up, but enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I created a little menubar app which [turns off bluetooth when your Mac is sleeping](https://github.com/odlp/bluesnooze/) (it's free). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem with bluetooth headset. How about toggle Bluetooth with AppleScript? [Scenario](http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html) gives the ability to run your script on sleep/wake.

> Scenario allows you to run AppleScripts when certain events happen. AppleScripts can be launched on Login, on Logout, when your Mac becomes Idle, no longer is Idle, goes to Sleep or Wakes up or when you hit a special Keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

I created a script that uses `blueutil` and `sleepwatcher` to essentially disable bluetooth when your macbook falls asleep, then re-enables it when it wakes up.

https://github.com/alb12-la/KBOS